# How can I search mysql for a single date?

Tags: mysql

I have a timestamp and I want to search for a single date but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
SELECT something from mytable WHERE timestamp = 'desiredDate'
```

If I include the hours mins and seconds in a range I can get it but there has to be a way to tell mysql that you want everything for a single day. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [TO_DAYS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) to turn the timestamp into a day number, then compare that with the desired day number:

```
SELECT foo FROM mytable WHERE TO_DAYS(timestamp) = TO_DAYS('2009-09-07');
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a bunch Paul! Worked like a sharm.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT something from mytable WHERE timestamp > 'desiredDate+00:00:00' and timestamp < 'desiredDate+23:59:59'
```

Or similar...

Comment: Can I specify the hours,etc in the query without the user having to do so?

Comment: This query seems to leave out the 59th second.

Comment: You are thinking about "AND timestamp < 'desiredDate+23:59:59'" vs. "and timestamp <= 'desiredDate+23:59:59'" ? I guess you're right!

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
SELECT myField FROM myTable WHERE timestamp LIKE '2009-08-07%'
```

to get all entries of a certain day.